# How to convert resized base64 image string into an actual file that I can upload to storage using lambda function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, sharp, supabase

I have a lambda function that uses `sharp` image resizing library.

This is my whole flow:

1. I convert my image file to base64 string then send it to the lambda function
2. inside function sharp resizes the image then sends base64 image string as a response
3. once I get the response on my client I try to use this function:

```
function urltoFile(url, filename, mimeType) {
 return fetch(url)
   .then(function (res) {
     return res.arrayBuffer();
   })
   .then(function (buf) {
     return new File([buf], filename, { type: mimeType });
   });
}

   const imageFileForUpload = await urltoFile(res.data, 'test.png', 'image/png');
```

to convert the string back into a file.
4. I try to upload this file to supabase storage

When I try to download this image file I get this error:

```
It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognise.
```

Here is my lambda function:

```
const Sharp = require("sharp");
const height=150;
const width= 150;
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        let request = JSON.parse(event.body)
    let base64String = request.base64String;
    base64String = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
    let inputBuffer = Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64');
    
                Sharp(inputBuffer)
                  .resize(width, height)
                  .toFormat("png")
                  .toBuffer()
              
              .then(buffer =>{
               
                  sendResponse(200, JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(buffer).toString('base64')), callback)

    
             }) 

};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using this [node package](https://github.com/anonyco/BestBase64EncoderDecoder)?  It makes a lot easier to handle base64 files.

Comment: @Mansueli can this be used client side?

Comment: Yep. You can see in the repo how to use it on the client side.